# Xpath returns always null for arXiv metadata

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm currently trying to parse some data from the arXiv. I was able to get the data in the xml format, but now I can't select certain elements.

For example, I want to get all authors from this xml file

http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=ListRecords&set=physics:hep-th&from=2015-03-30&until=2015-03-31&metadataPrefix=arXivRaw

The xpath query

```
//authors
```

or similar queries always return zero. Any ideas how to solve this problem would be great

Comment: how or where did you run the XPath query?

Comment: @har07 I tried several programs and copied one single entry from <record> to </record> into http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html , which all returned null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<authors>` nodes are in the *default namespace* `xmlns="http://arxiv.org/OAI/arXivRaw/"` which declared at the `<arXivRaw>` node level.

Many XPath platform (programming language API or other kind of XPath tools), provide a way to register mapping of namespace prefix to the corresponding namespace URI. In that case you need to register a prefix that points to `"http://arxiv.org/OAI/arXivRaw/"`, and use that prefix in your XPath. For example, assuming that the registered prefix named `d` :

```
//d:authors
```

But in case there is no way, you can resort to use combination of Xpath's `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` :

```
//*[local-name()='authors' and namespace-uri()='http://arxiv.org/OAI/arXivRaw/']
```

or maybe just ignore the namespace for simplicity* :

```
//*[local-name()='authors']
```

*) with risk of getting wrong nodes in case there are several nodes having same local name but different namespace

Comment: That works! Just one more quick question:  How can I then get the values of the element authors, i.e. the names without <authors></authors>?

Comment: add trailing `/text()`?

Comment: I tried  //*[local-name()='authors/text()'] which returns a zero

Comment: I meant `//*[local-name()='authors']/text()`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running into trouble with namespaces.  The difficulty is that the element you're after may be called `authors`, but it is living inside an arXiv-specific namespace.  You'll have to adapt the XPath expression with this in mind.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem comes from the declaration of two namespace but there is no prefix for them, so using `//authors` will try to find it using the default namespace and so returning no result.

Try this :

```
/OAI-PMH/ListRecords/record/metadata/arXivRaw/authors
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this query returns null, too